# Unable to show anything on edit form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I seem to unable to get the data from the database and display it on the edit form and when i checked all the syntax and the codes it doesnt seem to go wrong

My Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Buku extends Model
{
    //
}
```

This is my Controller code for edit:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        // find a post in the database and save as a variable
        $post = Buku::find($id);

        // return the view and pass in the variable we previously created
        return view('buku.edit')->with('buku', $post);
    }
```

Here is my view in for my edit form, I am using bootstrap modal for the form:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_buku" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Buku</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
      @if (isset($post))
        {!! Form::model($post, array('route' => array('buku.update' , $post->id), 'method' => 'PUT')) !!}
        @endif
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ Form::label('judul','Judul') }}
              {{ Form::text('judul', null, ["class" => 'form-control']) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ Form::label('deskripsi','Deskripsi') }}
              {{ Form::text('deskripsi', null, ["class" => 'form-control']) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             {{ Form::label('pengarang','Pengarang') }}
             {{ Form::text('pengarang', null, ["class" => 'form-control']) }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             {{ Form::label('tanggal_publikasi','Tanggal Publikasi') }}
             {{ Form::text('tanggal_publikasi', null, ["class" => 'form-control']) }}
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      {{ Form::submit('Edit', array('class' => 'btn btn-success')) }}   
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that i have to use the if isset to actually prevent an error called the Undefined variable error on my $post but it seems to not actually pass the value from the my database to the fields... I was wondering if the isset function is the cause.. I have tried to put the endif at the bottom of the code and the whole modal will not appear when I click on the link

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, i suggest to change your controller as follow:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    // find a post in the database and save as a variable
    $post = Buku::find($id);

    // return the view and pass in the variable we previously created
    return view('buku.edit')->with('post', $post);
}
```

I guess, it should solve your problem. Read more about passwing variables to views: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#passing-data-to-views

Comment: Still not coming up

Comment: Try to `{{dd($post)}}` in your blade to see, if you receive the data, and compare it with `dd($post)` in your controller below `$post = Buku::find($id);`

Comment: I did that and i put it even before the if statement and it throws me the Undefined variable: post (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\buddhaghosa\resources\views\modals\modal_edit_buku.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\buddhaghosa\resources\views\modals\modal_edit_buku.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

I notice in your controller you use `->with('buku', $post)`. This will send a variable called $buku along to the view, containing the buku that was found using `$post = Buku::find($id);`. Change that line to `->with('post', $post)`.

Secondly, I generally use `if (!empty($post))` instead of `isset`, since `empty()` evaluates both if it is set and if it is empty. According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php: `No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var == false.`

Thirdly, put your `@endif` after your `Form::close()`.

Fourthly, test to see if $post actually contains data. Either `{!! dd($post) !!}` before your if statement or use `else` to echo some text.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have put the @endif right after the Form::close() and the entire form except for the title of the form is not showing..

Also i put the {{! dd($post) !}} before the if statement and it throws the undefined variable $post error

Undefined variable: post (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\buddhaghosa\resources\views\modals\modal_edit_buku.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\buddhaghosa\resources\views\modals\modal_edit_buku.blade.php)

Comment: Assuming that you used {!! !!}, that `Undefined variable: post` tells you what your problem is. It cannot find $post, so it skips the `if (isset($post)` part, which would show your form.

Instead of `return view::make('buku.edit')->with('buku', $post);`, try `return view('buku.edit', compact($post));`

Comment: It still wont show up, I think the issue with it is that, it somehow does not pass the database values to the object called $post.. 

I tried the standard PHP function to call out a string from my controller,  it will not display any errors and it can display the string dynamically in my view.. Where as the $post that I declare and fill with the database values wont somehow show up in the view.. 

Tried this as well by reading the data from the database and display it dynamically in a view with the same errors or it wont show up..